# All vertices have degree 3 but graph is only 4-edge-colorable?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm trying to figure out the edge-coloring of the following graph.

There are three "rings" in the graph that are connected, the inner ring has 5 vertices, the outer ring has 5 vertices and the middle ring has 10 vertices.

All vertices have degree 3, but I'm not able to come up with a coloring that uses less than 4 colors.

I tried to color first the outer 5, then inner 5 then the middle ones in all variations ... but no way.

I find this pretty confusing, because it looks like it should work with less than four colors.

Is there a way I can ultimately prove/disprove that this graph indeed works with only four colors? I tried to check if it's bipartite (then it should work with four colors), but it's not.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The graph—which is, by the way, the [dodecahedral graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DodecahedralGraph.html)—admits a Hamiltonian circuit:
[image: Hamiltonian circuit of a dodecahedral graph]

Because the graph is cubic (i.e., all vertices have degree $3$), we can thus construct a $3$–edge-coloring of it by alternating the colors of the edges in the circuit and assigning the edges not in the circuit a third color.

[image: 3-edge coloring of a dodecahedral graph]

[Source for image](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:3-colored_dodecahedron.svg).

Comment: Nice thanks! That concludes the question I guess. What's the relation between the Hamiltonian circuit and the edge coloring?

Comment: Using the process in the answer, i.e., alternating the colors of the edges in a Hamiltonian circuit, then assigning $2$ (alternating) colors to the edges in the circuit, and a third color to the edges not in the circuit, always yields a $3$-edge-coloring of a cubic graph, since each vertex is incident to one edge of each of the three colors.

Comment: By the way, Hamiltonian cycles get their name from the Hamiltonian cycles on a dodecahedron; the great mathematician W. R. Hamilton tried to market [a game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosian_game) based on them.

Comment: You can also recover two other Hamiltonian circuits from that 3-colouring by deleting one of the other two colours; presumably on an actual dodecahedron they would just be rotations of each other?

Comment: @Neil I.I.r.c. up to isometries of the dodecahedron, all Hamiltonian circuits on the dodecahedral graph are the same.

Comment: A good answer. I'm still a bit confused by the general claim about the hamiltonian circuit and 2 colors. If there are odd number of edges, it would require 3 colors to color the circuit, right?

Comment: @justhalf If all the vertices have degree 3 then by the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) there must be an even number of vertices, and therefore any Hamiltonian circuit (if one exists) will have even length and produce a 3-colouring of the graph edges as described. Unfortunately there are [3-regular graphs without Hamiltonian circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_graph).

Comment: Nice, so it's not a general claim, but specific for even-length Hamiltonian circuit. Got it!

Comment: @justhalf The general statement is this: *If a cubic graph (one whose vertices all have degree $3$) admits a Hamiltonian circuit, then it is $3$-edge colorable.* Like Jaap Scherphuis wrote, any cubic graph has an even number of vertices, hence any Hamiltonian circuit of such a graph has an even number of edges. The claim does not apply in general to noncubic graphs (e.g., $K_n$ has a Hamiltonian circuit for $n \geq 3$ but is not $3$-colorable for $n \geq 5$).

Comment: Ah, I see that as the corollary of the other one, not aware that it's a more specific claim. Thanks. @TravisWillse

Answer (score 10):

3-valent graphs that cannot be 3-edge colored have a name: snarks. There are only 2 of them with 20 vertices, so you can try and check if your graph isomorphic to one of them.

See wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(graph_theory)

EDIT: your graph is planar and all planar 3-valent graphs are 3-edge colorable. This follows from the 4-color theorem (I admit: it is a bit killing a mosquito with an elephant but the proof of *how* it follows from the 4CT is simple and may help you find your coloring):

First 4-color your drawing when viewing it as a map. (So color the areas enclosed by the graph). Say you use colors red, green, blue and yellow.

Now edges that separate a red area from a green OR a blue area from a yellow one get color 1
Edges that separate red and blue OR yellow and green get color 2
Edges that separate red and yellow OR blue and green get color 3

This should give you your 3-edge coloring, provided that you managed to color the map first

Comment: 3-valent means all vertices have degree 3?

Comment: yes that is correct. Unrelated: isn't your graph the skeleton of a dodecahedron? That is known to *not* be a snark

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, never heard snark before. The 6 snarks with 20 vertices are listed in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.3032.pdf page 13. They don't look like the one I posted, so a three-edge-coloring must be possible after all, wow.

Comment: And thanks for the tip regarding trying to color it as a map, that's a genius idea.

Comment: 6? O I misremembered then. But see edit, the coloring must be possible.

Comment: Yes the genius idea goes back to, I believe, Tutte? One of the first people who studied snarks did it in an attempt to understand the 4 color problem (then still unproved). By the above clever coloring idea the 4CT is equivalent to the claim that no snark is planar. Then there is stronger conjecture that states that every snark has the Petersen graph as minor. This implies non-planarity and has the 'advantage' that it removes planarity and maps from the picture so that we only need to think about graphs as vertices and edges. But in the end the 4CT was proven much earlier than this conjecture

Comment: One stupid question regarding map coloring: Do we color the infinite face as well (like the area that is all around the outermost boundaries of the graph?)

Comment: yes! If it was a real world map I would use the color blue for the infinite region (ocean) but this is not obligatory. However the infinite region must get one of the 4 colors used for the finite regions - leaving it unclored would count as using a fifth color